# HTML/CSS: Repeat-y with blurred background

Tags: html, css, background, repeat, blur

### My problem

I would like to create a blurred background for my webpage, which repeats along the y-axis all the way to the bottom of the page, while the user scrolling to the bottom. The blurred background should behave as it does without blur in the following CSS:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('/assets/images/background/background-portal.webp');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;

  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

### Desired behavior

I want to achieve the following format, but with a blurred background. Background is an `1920x1080` size image, which repeats along the y-axis to the bottom of the page. The `#page-wrapper` is a transparent, 900px wide black box in the middle of the page, which height is determined by the length of the content it holds, and also this is what determines the height of the current page.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.webp');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Dark, transparent rectangle in the center of the page from top to bottom */
#page-wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(4, 12, 21, 0.604);
  position: absolute;
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: visible;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin: 30px;
}

/* Footer settings */
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(4, 12, 21, 0.604);
  color: rgba(255, 204, 0, 1);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<header>
</header>

<body>
  <div id="page-wrapper">
  <h1>Welcome!</h1>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc nec neque eu augue ultricies suscipit. Morbi semper mi ac enim hendrerit, nec consectetur libero suscipit. Curabitur et arcu ut massa sollicitudin lacinia. Nulla pellentesque, erat eu rhoncus tempor, odio leo aliquam leo, at rutrum erat mi non nisi. Donec vulputate hendrerit mauris non facilisis. Proin nec enim ac tortor mollis consequat eget nec mi. Mauris sapien metus, dapibus ut nibh non, vehicula iaculis elit. Praesent eu nulla accumsan, porttitor orci nec, aliquet elit. Praesent id efficitur urna.<br><br>Vivamus enim orci, vulputate nec leo vel, commodo lobortis erat. Integer aliquam dolor at egestas tempor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum eu finibus nibh. Vestibulum sed neque dignissim, dictum dui volutpat, tempus nisl. Maecenas laoreet faucibus lacinia. Quisque id quam iaculis nisi convallis interdum ac id justo. Praesent ac vulputate neque, at ornare turpis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec et congue odio, quis vestibulum massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Mauris non dolor tristique, vehicula nulla eu, pretium arcu. Sed finibus, urna ac cursus blandit, risus diam eleifend lorem, id cursus velit risus lacinia lectus.<br><br>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed dolor massa, bibendum eget interdum id, eleifend ut ligula. Phasellus neque nulla, suscipit vel maximus et, tempus quis dui. Cras suscipit eget justo in rhoncus. Etiam feugiat sem nibh, eget congue turpis maximus id. Vestibulum egestas condimentum diam, vitae imperdiet tellus luctus in. Curabitur elit sapien, blandit eget nisl imperdiet, dictum bibendum dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque venenatis mollis purus, a felis. Morbi at vehicula sapien.<br><br>Sed odio turpis, suscipit quis imperdiet eget, pulvinar in nulla. Sed ex elit, interdum eu cursus vitae, auctor dapibus sem. Cras mattis vel nibh ut tincidunt. Nulla gravida nisi nulla, et ultricies risus aliquam eu. Quisque malesuada auctor efficitur. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus mollis nibh ac diam tincidunt, vel faucibus nibh volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nunc metus, tempor ac tempor mollis, elementum id ligula. Vestibulum a velit ante. Aliquam feugiat a lectus at hendrerit. Etiam ut dapibus felis, at sagittis nibh. In gravida, odio eget bibendum dignissim, est libero egestas felis, ac commodo eros sapien et augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Praesent porttitor pretium velit, ut ultrices magna ultrices ac. Praesent nec imperdiet nunc.<br><br>Cras blandit ornare ullamcorper. Nam id gravida ex. Morbi venenatis lorem nec placerat condimentum. Aenean auctor, purus vitae varius feugiat, libero mi porttitor nulla, ut rutrum eros lectus eu mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec ut erat odio. Phasellus commodo consectetur sapien, nec consectetur nisi sodales eu. Vestibulum ac nunc erat. Fusce hendrerit sit amet lorem quis ultrices. Aenean eleifend dui a arcu accumsan egestas. Donec eget scelerisque arcu, id sodales nisi. Phasellus nec aliquet quam. Praesent maximus dolor vehicula massa maximus cursus.<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc nec neque eu augue ultricies suscipit. Morbi semper mi ac enim hendrerit, nec consectetur libero suscipit. Curabitur et arcu ut massa sollicitudin lacinia. Nulla pellentesque, erat eu rhoncus tempor, odio leo aliquam leo, at rutrum erat mi non nisi. Donec vulputate hendrerit mauris non facilisis. Proin nec enim ac tortor mollis consequat eget nec mi. Mauris sapien metus, dapibus ut nibh non, vehicula iaculis elit. Praesent eu nulla accumsan, porttitor orci nec, aliquet elit. Praesent id efficitur urna.<br><br>Vivamus enim orci, vulputate nec leo vel, commodo lobortis erat. Integer aliquam dolor at egestas tempor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum eu finibus nibh. Vestibulum sed neque dignissim, dictum dui volutpat, tempus nisl. Maecenas laoreet faucibus lacinia. Quisque id quam iaculis nisi convallis interdum ac id justo. Praesent ac vulputate neque, at ornare turpis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec et congue odio, quis vestibulum massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Mauris non dolor tristique, vehicula nulla eu, pretium arcu. Sed finibus, urna ac cursus blandit, risus diam eleifend lorem, id cursus velit risus lacinia lectus.<br><br>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed dolor massa, bibendum eget interdum id, eleifend ut ligula. Phasellus neque nulla, suscipit vel maximus et, tempus quis dui. Cras suscipit eget justo in rhoncus. Etiam feugiat sem nibh, eget congue turpis maximus id. Vestibulum egestas condimentum diam, vitae imperdiet tellus luctus in. Curabitur elit sapien, blandit eget nisl imperdiet, dictum bibendum dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque venenatis mollis purus, a felis. Morbi at vehicula sapien.<br><br>Sed odio turpis, suscipit quis imperdiet eget, pulvinar in nulla. Sed ex elit, interdum eu cursus vitae, auctor dapibus sem. Cras mattis vel nibh ut tincidunt. Nulla gravida nisi nulla, et ultricies risus aliquam eu. Quisque malesuada auctor efficitur. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus mollis nibh ac diam tincidunt, vel faucibus nibh volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nunc metus, tempor ac tempor mollis, elementum id ligula. Vestibulum a velit ante. Aliquam feugiat a lectus at hendrerit. Etiam ut dapibus felis, at sagittis nibh. In gravida, odio eget bibendum dignissim, est libero egestas felis, ac commodo eros sapien et augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Praesent porttitor pretium velit, ut ultrices magna ultrices ac. Praesent nec imperdiet nunc.<br><br>Cras blandit ornare ullamcorper. Nam id gravida ex. Morbi venenatis lorem nec placerat condimentum. Aenean auctor, purus vitae varius feugiat, libero mi porttitor nulla, ut rutrum eros lectus eu mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec ut erat odio. Phasellus commodo consectetur sapien, nec consectetur nisi sodales eu. Vestibulum ac nunc erat. Fusce hendrerit sit amet lorem quis ultrices. Aenean eleifend dui a arcu accumsan egestas. Donec eget scelerisque arcu, id sodales nisi. Phasellus nec aliquet quam. Praesent maximus dolor vehicula massa maximus cursus.
    </p>
    <footer id="footer">
      <p>
        Some footer...
      </p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### My attempt so far

To make the image blurry, my attempt was to create a class in my SCSS and pass it to a `div` in the HTML as follows:

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <!-- Header stuff -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Creates the background div -->
  <div class="body-bg"></div>

  <!-- Wrapper for the page content -->
  <!-- This is a black, transparent rectange,
       which stretches from the top to the bottom
       of the page. This encompasses all of the
       content on a page.
  -->
  <div id="#page-wrapper">
    <!-- Content... -->
  </div>
</body>
```

My SCSS for the `.body-bg{}` class currently looks like the following (**UPDATED with the `#page-wrapper` id**):

```css
.body-bg {
  background-image: url('/assets/images/background/background-portal.webp');
  background-repeat: repeat-y;

  -webkit-filter: blur($blurAmount);
  -moz-filter: blur($blurAmount);
  -o-filter: blur($blurAmount);
  -ms-filter: blur($blurAmount);
  filter: blur($blurAmount);
  transform: scale(1.05);

  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Dark, transparent rectangle in the center of the page from top to bottom */
#page-wrapper {
  background-color: $baseColor;
  position: absolute;
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Which I see, that isn't working. This blurs the background image correctly, places it behind all page elements, but isn't repeating it along the y-axis. Only the first copy of the image shows up at the top of the page.

#### Note

I want to avoid setting the `position` element to

```css
position: fixed;
```

in any ways, I would like a repeating background. **I'm open to any other solution, which can be utilized on a strictly static webpage, since I'm using Jekyll on GitHub pages.** Thank you for any of your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

EDIT: I've added `background-size: 100% auto;` to your code along with a `min-height: 10000vh` because of your requirement to not use `position: fixed;`

```css
.main-content  {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/04/15/12/12/flowers-5046413__340.jpg");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 900px;
  background-color: rgba(4, 12, 21, 0.604);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="main-content"></div>

<div class="content">Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No. It blurs the content on the page (everything inside the `<body></body>` tag), but not the image itself. I noticed, that you need to avoid passing `blur()` to the body element, but need to make a separate `div` for the background itself and pass the CSS to that element.

Comment: You're right about the body tag. - See my updated snippet, is that what you want?

Comment: I appreciate your help! But no, this is not exactly the behaviour I want. It actually produces the same output as my original attempt did. I fear that maybe I wasn't accurate enough. I'll update my post but write a few words here too first.

On my website, the content div with the id `#page-wrapper` (or the `content` class in your answer) is a vertically centered, transparent, 900px wide div element, which extends from the top to the bottom of the page, always. I want my 1920x1080px background image to repeat along the y-axis when a user scrolls to the bottom of the page with lot of content.

Comment: I've updated my snippet using your code and added `background-size: 100% auto;` for your image so it stretches across the entire page and only repeats on the y-axis. After running the snippet click view in full page. You will see that the background image won't repeat horizontally.

Comment: Yes, this is much closer to what I wanted to achieve! It has really only two problems now: 1. there is now a scrollbar horizontally, which isn't desired, and 2. I still wan't the background to go only to the bottom of the page (which is determined by the content on the page inside my `<div id="#page-wrapper"></div>` block). I'll insert a code snippet to my post to show exactly what I wan't, but with a blurred background.

Comment: Code has been updated. - I removed the min-height from the main-content div and added some additional code.

Answer (score 0):

**How about like this??**

```css
.main-content  {
  background-image: url("https://i2.wp.com/wallur.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rain-background-1.jpg?fit=1920%2C1080");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.content {
  z-index:999;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color:white;
  font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="main-content"></div>

<div class="content">Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some conrtyrtytent<br/>Some content<br/>Some contenrtyrtt<br/>Sortyme content<br/>Some content<br/>Some conyrtytent<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some rtyrty<br/>Some content<br/>Some condfsrtytent<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some contrtyrtyent<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some cortyntent<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some conrtyrtent<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some rty<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some conrtyrttent<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some 123<br/>Some 123content<br/>Some cont3213ent<br/>Some co12312312ntent<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some cont12312ent<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some1231 content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some cont123123ent<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some content<br/>Some c123ontent<br/>Some content<br/></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is actually my plan B, if I can't find any solution to my original problem. This is completely good however, the background is blurred, but it is fixed to the viewport. That's why I added a **Note** to my post, that I don't want the `.main-content` to be fixed.